# Road bike around 1000 dollars

Tags: road-bike

I am confused between the Giant SCR 1 and Specialized Allez E5 Sport. I have not ridden any of them as I cannot have test rides. I have heard great reviews about the Allez but the dealer is quite far away unlike the giant which has a dealer close by. I am not quite sure about how good the SCR is as I have seen no review. Also if there are alternatives please say but I would like to buy one among these two.

Comment: Hi Ronit - this seems entirely opinion based. Questions like that are explicitly off topic.

Comment: Buy a **used** bike!

Answer (score 2):

A quick look at the web pages and specs reveals they are pretty much equally specified: Aluminum frame, carbon fork, Sora group-set. Minor differences in geometry.

That one that is right for you is the one that feels right when riding it. If one is in stock in the size that fits you and the other is not, get the one that fits.

If you can ride them both and can't decide based on ride, choose the one that comes in the color you like the best.

I can't emphasize how important test rides are to assess fit and how the bike feels to you. In my opinion if a bike store won't let you test ride they don't deserve your money (here in the US anyway, I understand things may be different where you are located).